# PuTTY Linux console enters UTF-8 numbers, not ASCII

Tags: linux, console, putty, utf

I'm using PuTTY to connect Linux from Windows.
When I enter

> ./tool < number >

Tool gets UTF-8 text with RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE except normal ascii and tools dont work.
[gdb output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBRY9.png)

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is new putty option Arabic Text Shaping.
Need to disable it in settings.
This new stuff really breaks many tools.